# expected declaration or statement at end of input (Single linked list )

Tags: c, data-structures

Sigle linked list

i cant run this program (
Single linked ist )

i need help

it always gives me " expected declaration or statement at end of input "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
int data;
struct node *link;}node;
node *root=NULL;
void addafter (){
node *temp,*p;
printf("Entre Location ?\n");
int loc,i ;
int len=length ();
scanf("%d",&loc);
if (loc > len ){
    printf("Error \n");
}
else {
    p=root;
    while(i<loc){
        p=p->link;
        i++;}
temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 printf("Entre node data ?\n");
 scanf("%d",&temp->data);
 temp->link=NULL;
 temp->link=p->link;
 p->link=temp;
}

void delet (){
    node *temp;
    int location;
    printf("Entre location to delet ");
    scanf("%d",&location);
    if (location > length()){
        printf("Error \n");
    }
    else if (location==1){
            temp=root;
            root=temp->link;
            temp->link=NULL;}
    else {
node *K=root;
node *q;
        int i=1;
        while (i < (location-1)){
        K=K->link;
        i++;}
    q=K->link;
    K->link=q->link;
    q->link=NULL;
    free(q);
    }


}
void append (){
node *temp;
temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("Entre node data \n");
scanf("%d",&temp->data);
temp->link=NULL;
if (root==NULL){
    root=temp;}
    else {
    node *p;
        p=root;
        while (p->link !=NULL){
            p=p->link;
        }
        p->link=temp;
    }
int length (){
node *t;
t=root;
int counter;
while (t!=NULL){
    counter ++;
    t=t->link;
}
return counter;
}
void add (){
node *a;
a=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("Entre Node data \n");
scanf("%d",&a->data);
a->link=NULL;
if (root==NULL){
    root=a;
}
else{
a->link=root;
root=a;
}
       }
void Display (){
node *temp;
temp=root;
if (temp==NULL){
    printf("List is empty \n");
}
else {
    while (temp!= NULL){
        printf("%d-->",temp->data);
        temp=temp->link;
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
}
int main()
{node *root=NULL;
root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int ch;
   while (1){
    printf("Linked List Operations !!");
    printf("1.Append \n");
    printf("2.Add \n");
    printf("3.Add at after \n");
    printf("4.Length \n");
    printf("5.Display \n");
    printf("6.Delet \n");
    printf("7.Quit \n");
    printf("Entre your choice \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
switch (ch){
    case 1 : append();
    break;
    case 2 : add();
    break;
    case 3 : addafter();
    break;
    case 4 : length();
    break;
    case 5 : Display();
    break;
    case 6 : delet ();
    break;
    case 7 : exit(1);
    default: printf("Invalid input \n");

  }
 }
}
```

Error shown
Build: Debug in single (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)
In function 'addafter'
warning: implicit declaration of function 'length' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration
In function 'append'
110warning: 'main' is normally a non-static function [-Wmain]|
In function 'main':|warning: variable 'root' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|
In function 'append':|
143|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
In function 'addafter':|
143|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: If that is all of your code, you are missing `#include` statements and definitions of types and functions. If that is not all of your code, then edit the question to provide a [mre], including **complete** source code that reproduces the problem and the **exact** complete text of the compiler messages.

Comment: This is _not_ the code you're compiling. It complains about missing `node` definition and missing function definitions (e.g. `append`) but it does _not_ complain about: `" expected declaration or statement at end of input "`

Answer (score 0):

It is giving this error as some closing braces are missing in the code.
Please put one closing brace '}' at the end of addafter function and one where append function ends.